# Import Voozanoo data into R

Tags: r

[Voozanoo](http://www2.voozanoo.net/) allows exporting the data in various formats. What's the best way to import the data into R?

I tried the CSV export, it worked, but extracting the codes and values of categorical variables from the HTML descriptions of the tables was cumbersome. Has anybody tried which export format enables the easiest and most complete import of the data into R?

Comment: What are your other options?

Comment: @nograpes: The data are in Voozanoo. I want to perform most of the analyses in R. The rest is flexible. Do you see other options?

Comment: No, I meant, what are your other options for exporting the data? You mentioned CSV as one of them. I don't really get why you have HTML in the CSV, but it shouldn't be too hard to extract even the HTML. Why don't you post a sample of the CSV extract?

Comment: @nograpes: If I have to figure out the solution I assume I will be able to. I posted the question to SE to know if someone has already figured the answer out.